# Castle Windsor : Cycle detected in configuration

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

am using castle windsor via xml configurations.. and recently am getting this error after adding a new dependency in constructor input parameter.. any idea how i can provide an override in windsor dependency xml file..

```
Cycle detected in configuration.
Component class1 has a dependency on class2 but it doesn't provide an override.
You must provide an override if a component has a dependency on a service that it - itself - provides

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IOrderApplicationService.method1()
   at OrderApplicationServiceClient.method1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the approach detailed [in the documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components.ashx#Component_with_parameters_13)?